# How do I create a null column but with default value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

I am trying to create a Shopping Cart, where customer could choose if they want delivery or store pickup for their items. Default price for delivery would be $10. How do I set the default value of delivery to be $10, but only when Customer picks Delivery?

Comment: Did you try it to solve? Some SQL Queries that makes columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean a computed column :

```
CREATE TABLE YourTableName
( 
   ....
, DeliveryCharge AS CASE
       WHEN TYPE == 1 THEN 10
       WHEN TYPE == 0 THEN NULL
   END
)
```

Or you can create a Trigger that sets the value on INSERT/UPDATE on that table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_YourTableName_DeliveryCharge
ON YourTableName
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
UPDATE YourTableName SET DeliveryCharge = CASE TYPE WHEN 1 THEN 10 ELSE NULL END
go
```

Assuming you have a column named TYPE that specifies if it is a delivery or not.

Answer (score 0):

you should set default value to 10 in SQL server and pass null(dont pass anything ) to SQL server, when customer picks Delivery.

so the part of logic will be in your code , and other part in SQL server.

Comment: are you using orm ? or you are jyst making insert string in your code? if you are making insert string dont pass anything , not even 0 .

Comment: if you are using EF , c# is strong type , you cant pass null as int , bigin , or.. it is always 0 . so you have to pass 10 in your code in this case.

Comment: As indicated by the lack of a blue box around my name, I'm not the OP, so it's not my code. But if you set a default of 10, you _must_ pass 0 or some other non-`null` value when the default is not applicable, e.g. when store pickup (no charge) is selected. I was saying you should clarify what you would do in that situation, because that's the other half of the answer.

Comment: 0 is not null . 0 is zero. can you you post code that you are trying to insert ?

Comment: I know very well that "0 is not null", but thanks for assuming I don't. I'll say it again: I'm not the OP. It's not my code. I'm not trying to insert anything. I'm asking what you would do in a situation where your default is not the correct value for the current transaction, as a complete answer would cover both. Clearly the solution is to pass 0, thus overriding the default of 10. Also, "pass null(dont pass anything)" is ambiguous. Which is it? Clearly, passing `null` would insert `null`, not the default. So you have to omit the column altogether from the statement or pass `default` instead.